# Unable to run torque/pbs server on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, torque

I downloaded the torque repo with

```
git clone https://github.com/adaptivecomputing/torque/
```

In my dockerfile I install it with

```
FROM nistmni/minc-toolkit:1.9.16

COPY "torque" "/execute/torque"

WORKDIR /execute/torque

RUN ./autogen.sh && \
    ./configure --prefix=$home && \
    make && \
    make install
```

This appears to work, and the various pbs commands are available in the PATH. (nistmni/minc-toolkit:1.9.16 is Ubuntu 16.04 64bit)

(I am currently root)

I now run

```
./torque.setup root localhost
```

Which from everything I've read is the first step to actually starting the server.  But I get the following error(s):

```
set server operators += root@localhost
Can not resolve name for server bbdeb8fab105. (rc = -1 - )
Cannot resolve specified server host 'bbdeb8fab105'.
qmgr: cannot connect to server  (errno=15010) Access from host not allowed, or unknown host
ERROR: cannot set TORQUE admins
Can not resolve name for server bbdeb8fab105. (rc = -1 - )
Cannot resolve specified server host 'bbdeb8fab105'.
qterm: could not connect to server '' (15010) Access from host not allowed, or unknown host
```

Could any experienced torque users help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the randomisation of the hostname in Docker is causing the issues.  Before running

```
./torque.setup root
```

Call

```
echo "localhost" > /var/spool/torque/server_name
```